# Showing video output with Nvidia VPI

Tags: python, opencv, nvidia

Following the example from

https://docs.nvidia.com/vpi/1.1/algo_persp_warp.html

I'm trying to do some projection on an input video from a webcam. The Jetson AGX Xavier is the hardware. The following code is running without errors. My question is, how do I show the live output? I noticed the last bit is set up to output video to a file.

I'm looking for something like `cv2.imshow()`, but when I use OpenCV to show the output, I get an error:

```
mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
-Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
-Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

```
import cv2
import vpi

cap =  cv2.VideoCapture(0)


xform = [[  0.5386, 0.1419, -74   ],
         [ -0.4399, 0.8662, 291.5   ],
         [ -0.0005, 0.0003, 1     ]]

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
inSize = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)


outVideo = cv2.VideoWriter('perspwarp_python.mp4',
                            fourcc, fps, inSize)


while True:

    _, frame = cap.read()


    with vpi.Backend.CUDA:
        frame = vpi.asimage(frame).convert(vpi.Format.NV12_ER)

    with vpi.Backend.CUDA:
        output = frame.perspwarp(xform)

    with vpi.Backend.CUDA:
        output = output.convert(vpi.Format.RGB8)

    with output.rlock():
        outVideo.write(output.cpu())
```

Comment: imshow requires numpy arrays

Comment: Could I convert "outVideo" to a numpy array?

Comment: no, it's a VideoWriter object. why would you want to do that and what sense would that make? why would you want to "display" the thing that _writes_ your data, when you *should* want to display **the data**? -- you say you're calling `imshow` but I don't see that code... show the code. please review [mre].

Comment: Right, so I need to show 'output'. I tried that with cv2.imshow('video', output) but I get the same error. Think it's going to look messy in the comments, but I put cv2.imshow below the last bit of code. Basically, I want to perform the perspective warp using the VPI method, but then show the output as video and not save it to a file.

Comment: what's the value of `type(output)`? is that type something `imshow` should understand? what's the value of `type(output.cpu())`?

Comment: I was sure I'd tried them both, but I can see the type of output.cpu() is a numpy array. Thanks Christoph. Can't believe this took me a week to figure out.. Can move on with the project now. Noticed some drops in framerate though. Was hoping the VPI methods were faster. Need to look into CPU / GPU usage probably.

Comment: yeah that's what the MRE article is for, to remind people to cultivate useful debugging skills. -- transfer between host and device always costs time. if you want to display the data, and it's on the gpu already, see about opengl interop, and how to throw that onto the display given whatever gui toolkit you really mean to use. I heard rumors that OpenCV's imshow _can_ work with opengl textures, so that's interoperable with openCL.

Comment: oh, also, the error message indicates that imshow considers a `cv::cuda::GpuMat` edible... since you already deal with CUDA, well, nvidia stuff, there's probably a way to twist your VPI thingies into cuda thingies, and then into opencv's cuda wrapper thingies.